# Python - Unexpected Import Occuring

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython, jupyter-notebook, python-import

I'm hoping someone can provide some insight on some extra name bindings that Python3 is creating during an import. Here's the test case:

I created a test package called `spam` (original, I know). It contains 3 files as follows:

[image]

The contents of the files are as follows:

`__init__.py`:

```
from .foo import Foo  
from .bar import Bar
```

`foo.py`:

```
def Foo():
    pass
```

`bar.py`:

```
def Bar():  
    pass
```

Pretty simple stuff. When I import the `spam` package, I can see that it creates name bindings to the `Foo()` and `Bar()` *functions* in the `spam` namespace, which **is** expected. What isn't expected is that it also binds a name to the `foo` and `bar` *modules* in the `spam` namespace, as shown below.

[image]

What's even more interesting is that these extra name bindings to the module don't occur if I import the `Foo()` and `Bar()` functions in `__main__`, as shown below:

[image]

Reading through the documentation on the import statement (language ref and tutorial), I don't see anything that would cause this to be.

Can anyone shed some light on why, when importing a function from a module inside a package, it also binds a name to the module containing the function?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - that is correct, and part of Python import mechanism.

When you import a module a lot of things happen, but we can focus on a few:

1) Python checks if the module is already loaded - to that means, it checks if it is qualifyed bane (name with dots) is under sys.modules

2) If not, it actually loads the module: that includes checking for pre-compiled cached bytecode files, parse, compile the .py file otherwise, etc...

3) It actually makes the name bindings as they are in the `import` command: that is "from .foo import Foo" creates a variable "Foo" in the current namespace that points to the "spam.foo.Foo"  object.

Perceive that the module is always loaded as a whole - and associated in the sys.modules dictionary.  Besides that, the import process makes all sub-modules to a package available in the module namespace visible in that package - that is what causes the names "foo" and "bar" do be visible in your Spam package.

You could, at the end of your `__init__.py` file delete the names  "foo" and "bar" - but that will break the way expected import and usage of spam.foo works in funamental ways - basically: `sys.modules["spam.foo"]` will exist, but`sys.modules["spam"].foo` wont - meaning that after 
one tries to do:

```
import spam.foo
spam.foo.Foo()
```

Python will yield a name error on "foo".

The import machinery will report it as existing (it is in sys.modules), so it does nothing. But "spam.foo" has been removed, so it can't be reached.

Comment: Thanks for that detailed response. I found it well laid out. I think the following quote nails it:  *"Besides that, the import process makes all sub-modules to a package available in the module namespace visible in that package - that is what causes the names "foo" and "bar" do be visible in your Spam package."*    Do you know of any place in the documentation that spells that out? Or is it something you found by reading the source code?